# Swift didSet called but not updating UILabel - iOS Property observer

Tags: ios, swift, properties

Any idea why my label.text is only updating when the count finishes?

`didSet` is called.  But the `label.text = String(counter)` appears to do nothing.

**Swift 5**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var counter:Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("old value \(oldValue) and new value: \(counter)")
            label.text = String(counter)
            sleep(1).  // just added to show the label.text is not updating
        }
    }

    @IBAction func start_btn(_ sender: Any) {
        for _ in 1...3 {
            counter += 1
        }
    }
}
```

`didSet` code is called from the Main Thread.   It is all wired correctly with Storyboards ( not `SwiftUI`).

You can see the `didSet` code is called.

```
old value 0 and new value: 1. Main thread: true
old value 1 and new value: 2. Main thread: true
old value 2 and new value: 3. Main thread: true
```

Comment: Never, ever call `sleep` in an iOS app. That will block the main thread, which means your app will be frozen for a whole second with `sleep(1)`.

Comment: I was not planning on leaving the `Sleep` call.  I added it to help show SO readers what was happening. As I said, the didSet was always invoked from the mainThread (Thread.isMainThread).

Comment: Not sure how adding `sleep` would help show that. Also what are you trying to achieve? When you press the start button the counter would go from 0 to 3 almost immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to make some kind of counter which starts at 0 and stops at 3. If that is the case you should not call `sleep` (which blocks the main thread).

edit: apparently the `sleep` call was added for demonstration purposes?
In any case the reason why your label seems like it is only updating when the count finishes is because the `for` loop runs too quickly for the UI to update on each `counter` increment.

Rather use `Timer`:

```
counter = 0
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
    self.counter += 1

    if self.counter >= 3 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

This is based on my rough understanding on what you're aiming to achieve.

You could also `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`:

```
func countUp() {
    guard counter < 3 else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.counter += 1
        fire()
    }
}
```

For short time intervals, the difference between the two approaches is going to be pretty insignificant. For really accurate time counting, one shouldn't rely on either though, but rather use `Date` with a `Timer` that fires say every tenth of a second, and updates counter by rounding to the nearest second (for example).

Comment: Thanks for spending time on the answer @shim

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like following

```
@IBAction func start_btn(_ sender: Any) {
    updateCounter()
}

func updateCounter() {
    if counter == 3 {
        return
    } else {
        counter += 1
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
            self.updateCounter()
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever call `sleep` in an iOS app. That will block the main thread, which means your app will be frozen for a whole second with `sleep(1)`.

This means that the main thread will be blocked while the loop in `start_btn` finishes and hence the UI can only be updated after the loop has already finished.

If you want to make the text change every second, modify the button action to

```
@IBAction func start_btn(_ sender: Any) {
    for i in 1...3 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i), execute: {
            self.counter += 1
        })
    }
}
```

and remove `sleep(1)` from `didSet`.